# Passing values from a table to Oracle query in dataflowtask?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, oracle-sqldeveloper, ssis

```
Employee:

EmployeeID     EmployeeName      EmployeeNumber     StartDate        StopDate
   1            Tom                 7887             3/1/2014         3/1/2015
   2            Harry               7888             3/1/2013         3/1/2015
   3            Frank               7889             3/1/2012         3/1/2015
   4            John                7890             3/1/2011         3/1/2015
```

I have an Employee table in Sql Server .I am using employee information to pass values in to an Oracle query to get the data from Oracle using data flow task.
 But I never tried with pl/sql as it looking different from sql.
 My oracle query looks like

```
SELECT *
    FROM Components A INNER JOIN Values b
    on A.Rowid=B.Rowid
    and A.Contact IN(:EmployeeName)
    and A.Sub IN(:EmployeeNumber )
    WHERE
A.time BETWEEN TO_DATE(:StartDate) AND TO_DATE(:EndDate) + 0.99999


How can I pass my Employee table values in to above sql query using for loop Container.
```

Comment: Care to leave a comment Mr Down Voter??

Comment: NOT THE DOWN VOTER :) -- What would your loop container  loop over? In other words would the Oracle query get fired for every EmployeeName, EmployeeNumber combination?

Comment: @godzilla2014  Yes oracle query should be fired for every EmployeeName, EmployeeNumber .

Comment: "I am looking how to pass the values to from the table to variables in SP using for loop container in SSIS. " Are you using an Oracle SP now instead of the query? Or did you have any issues passing in the variables to the query?

Comment: @godzilla2014: i am using execute sql task to get all the values from the table.My next step is i am using for each loop conatiner where i a getting single row for varaible .How can i assign first row values to User defined variables : EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EmployeeNumber, StartDate,StopDate so i can use them in DFT for Oracle source??

Comment: @godzilla2014  issues passing in the variables to the query

Comment: I have updated my earlier answer with the information you need. Let me know if you still are facing issues.

Comment: @godzilla2014 the problem is in the 4 the step.I have creates 5 varaibels EmployeeID,EmployeeName,EmployeeNumber,StartDate,        StopDate by inreasing index value 0 to 4.After that I am using DFT Where SELECT * FROM Employee
where  
EmployeeID=? and EmployeeName=? and EmployeeNumber=? and StartDate=? and StopDate=?

Comment: @godzilla2014: But my DFT WAS FAILING (I SKIPPED ORACLE SOURCE AND TESTING WITH SQL SOURCE).

Comment: @godzilla2014 [OLE DB Source [1]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53975/discussion-between-user3203331-and-godzilla2014).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query Oracle just as you do your SQL Server. In your case you would have to build the Oracle query from your look up variables. For example your variable ExtractSQL would be an expression like below-

"SELECT *
    FROM Components A INNER JOIN Values b
    on A.Rowid=B.Rowid
    and A.Contact = '" + @[User::EmployeeName] +"' and A.Sub ='"+ @[User::EmployeeNumber] + "' WHERE
A.time BETWEEN TO_DATE('"+ @[User::StartDate] +"') AND TO_DATE('"+ @@[User::EndDate] +"') + 0.99999"

Depending on how you have stored the date on your end you might have to pass a second parameter to the To_Date function for the format Eg. TO_DATE ('2014-05-14 15:01:27' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')

-To answer your question about setting the variables.

1. Create a variable called EmployeeRecordset of type "Object".
2. In your execute SQL task in the Result Set tab, have  Result Name 0 and Variable Name as User::EmployeeRecordset.
3. In your for each loop, set the Enumerator as ForEach ADO Enumerator, Set the ADO Object Source Variable as  User::EmployeeRecordset. Enumeration mode you can leave it as Rows in First table.
4. In Variable mappings set your row level variables  - i.e. Employee Number, Employee Name etc. in the order it is returned from the query starting at an index of 0.

Now you should be able to use the variables inside the loop to form your Oracle query.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother.inputs to oracle must look like   14-MAY-2014 .

Comment: That's the default but you can control the format by using the second parameter to the To_DATE function. Anyways glad I could help...

Comment: he single quotation mark at line number "15", character number "32", was not expected.

Comment: Can you send me the query expression you have used?

Comment: "SELECT *
    FROM Components A
 WHERE  A.Contact  IN "'+ @[EmployeeName]] +"'

Comment: You had the quotation marks in the wrong order and you would also need   () around theemployee name for "IN" to work - "SELECT * FROM Components A WHERE A.Contact IN ('"+ @[EmployeeName]+"')"

Comment: I am using below query to get data between dates but i am getting error BETWEEN TO_DATE('" + (DT_WSTR, 10) @[User::StartDate] +
"', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE('" + (DT_WSTR, 10) @[User::EndDate] + 
"', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')+ 0.99999

Comment: A truncation occurred during evaluation of the expression.

Comment: Can you check the format of the value that is set for  @[User::StartDate] and @[User::EndDate]? Obviously the (DT_WSTR, 10) is truncating the string. Instead of having the variables  @[User::StartDate] and @[User::EndDate] as datetime type, have them as String Type.

Comment: StartDate and Enddate is in data time data type...i changed (DT_WSTR, 10) to 30 it worked and came with new error full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Comment: what is the + 0.99999 in your query for? Can you see if it works after removing it?

Comment: If you have NULL values for StartDate and EndDate then you would need the expression to handle those.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

1. Dataflow task (DFT1) to build a rowset - that we would loop though in Oracle.
2. User defined variables : @EmployeeID, @EmployeeName, @EmployeeNumber, @StartDate,@StopDate
3. DFT1 - A sql query to load the data into a recordset destination. You can write the query as your wish to format the data, that is, for example define @StartDate as string and convert '3/1/2014' into the desired date format in Oracle
4. Now use foreachLoop enumerator for the Ado .NET recordsets and loop through.
5. Inside the foreachLoop enumerator, you should have the data flow task that uses the variables above to form a SQL statement (Meant to be executed in Oracle) using expression. You will need to use SQL Command from expression option there
6. Destination!

Comment: I am totally confused how can we assign my first row values to the User defined variables : EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EmployeeNumber, StartDate,StopDate.

Comment: You can see it [here](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/106/posts/11122/loop-through-each-record-in-a-text-file-recordset-destination.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879316.aspx). 

This is the simplest way to loop through all your records.